# Spring Cloud Data Flow UI

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

We have a Spring Batch Application that is triggered by a Task Command Line Runner that is periodically triggered. We are looking for a UI to view the Job Execution status, can we use the Spring Cloud Data Flow UI dependency and get the UI view capability of these Job Executions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just use the SCDF GUI outside on your own *without* SCDF — they are tightly coupled.

When Task/batch-job are launched from SCDF, the task/job executions are automatically tracked in the common datasource; likewise, the SCDF GUI will show task and batch-job details automatically, as well [see [task executions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard-tasks) / [job executions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard-jobs)].

Whether using a [scheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard-task-scheduling) or [manually launching](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_launching_tasks) the jobs, as far as the launch from both approaches goes through SCDF, everything should just work.

Comment: Thank you for the response and clarification!

Comment: We added the full SCDF bundle and used it as a separate Spring Boot Application using the Spring Data Flow Parent. However, the Batch Job Applications are separate from this  application.The scheduling and manual launch does not go through the SCDF application, but both the application share the same datasource. Using this approach, the SCDF UI's Job Executions tab is able to display the Job Execution details but in few occasions, it is not able to display the details, when we verified the logs we are seeing error messages saying table "taskdefintion" not found.

Comment: Is there a way to force the SCDF Spring Boot Application to create the Batch / Task tables in the datasource and make the Batch Job Applications use it? We just want make the Job Executions displayed in the SCDF UI tab.

Comment: `"taskdefintion" not found` <- this is the key. SCDF UI and the Backend are tightly coupled in the sense each of the tasks must have to be represented in a definition, and that is persisted in SCDF's database. Without that footprint, most of the SCDF capabilities won't work as expected.